# Percentage of responses in array for a graph population?

Tags: php, mysql

I have this little query that produces the percentage of responses correctly.

```
$pdo->query("SELECT avg(pineapple = 'yes')*100 FROM responses");
```

But what I need to do, is get columns question1,2,3,4 columns together where they are arrayed as columnname => percentage for my graph.

Since I'm not getting two fields in the SELECT, I am unclear how to move forward to set up array like I have before:

```
$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$jsnarray = array();
$json = json_encode($results);
foreach($results as $k => $v){
    $jsnarray[] = array('question' => $results[$k]['COLUMN???'], 'value' => $results[$k]['question1']);
};
```

Update:
To clarify desired output: an array like:

```
[column1name] => column yes response %
[column2name] => column2 yes response %
```

so it would theoretically be:

```
[pineapple] => 55%
[cheesecurds] => 80%
```

Which allows the bar graph to be labeled pineapple with the value of 55% and so on.

Comment: You only have one column in the result. It's unclear what  you are trying to do.

Comment: Trying to get 4 columns, which in code, don't know how to do.  SELECT avg(pineapple, mushroom, anchovy, cheesecurd = yes) doesn't work.

Second how to reference the name of the column in the array output.

So I want to see:
Pinapple => 25%
Mushroom => 42%
Anchovy => 1%
Cheesecurd => 99%

Comment: You should normalize your table design. Pineapple, mushroom and so on should not be column names

Comment: Work on your SQL, get the desired result, only then start with PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should normalize your database design. With your current design, you have to list each column separately. What happens if you need to add a new ingredient?

You could modify your existing SQL to calculate an average of each column like so:

```
SELECT 
    avg(pineapple = 'yes')*100 AS pineapple, 
    avg(mushroom = 'yes')*100 AS mushroom, 
    avg(anchovy = 'yes')*100 AS anchovy, 
    avg(cheesecurd = 'yes')*100 AS cheesecurd
FROM responses
```

Then in PHP, you can just access it as you normally would with any other column.

```
$averages = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo "Anchovies: ".$averages['anchovy'];
```

Comment: Unfortunately that is not what google form outputs into a sheet.  I will have to move away from using a google form and using my own form to do what you suggest, but it is the right path to make this normalized.

Answer (score 0):

For a non normalized database like one using imports from google forms:

```
$stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT 100*avg(pineapple = 'yes') AS Pineapple, 100*avg(pepperoni = 'yes') AS Pepperoni, 100*avg(mushrooms = 'yes') AS Mushrooms, 100*avg(anchovies = 'yes') AS Anchovies FROM responses");
$averages = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$jsonEncodedData=json_encode($averages);
header( 'Content-type: application/json' );
echo $jsonEncodedData;
```

I did 100*avg for percentage.

Again, don't use this if you can help it.